# Custom Cursor changing when hovering Child Compobent

Tags: reactjs

I have a React App with a global custom cursor (not only a png changed in CSS, but a colored circle-div that‘s following the mouse).
My App consists of various child components (project teasers), when hovering those project teaser components the cursor component should change size, color and text content.

I have no experience with Redux so far, but do I need to store the cursor state in Redux for such a scenario or can I pass it down another way?

Thanks.

Comment: You can either use react context/redux or manually pass down the props each component. If you want study react context, here's a good article — https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-the-new-react-context-api-fce011e7d87

Comment: That‘s exactly what I was looking for. Really appreciate your help and quick reply @Saqib

Comment: I am glad I was able to help you. I am posting it as an answer, kindly accept that as answer. So your question will be market answers and might be helpful for the other people searching for a similar question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use react context/redux or manually pass down the props each component. If you want study react context, here's a [good article](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-the-new-react-context-api-fce011e7d87).